# `ls > fifo &` blocks fish shell

Tags: fish

In fish shell, this blocks the input:

```sh
$ mkfifo fifo
$ ls > fifo &
```

However this works in zsh and bash.

So how can I start this kind of background process which stdout is redirected to a fifo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written, this will probably never work in fish shell. fish always opens redirections before fork, which will deadlock in this case, as the fifo has no reader.

I think the best workaround is to make someone else open the file, for example `tee`:

```
 > mkfifo fifo
 > ls | tee fifo >/dev/null &
```